# Separate a string using strpbrk , with delimiter ">>"?

Tags: c, string

I write a program that gets as an input any string that contain the following characters :

```
& , > , < , SPACE (e.g " ")
```

The delimiters are written like this : `char delimiters[] = " &<>";` , and I use them with the `strpbrk` command.

I need to add the delimiter `">>"` to this group . How can I do this ?

If I just write : `char delimiters[] = " &<>>>";` , the compiler doesn't treat the `>>` accordingly .

Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strpbrkEx(const char *str, char **strs){
    char *minp=(char*)-1, *p;
    if(NULL==str || NULL==strs)return NULL;
    while(*strs){
        p=strstr(str, *strs++);
        if(p && minp > p)
            minp = p;
    }
    if(minp == (char*)-1) return NULL;
    return minp;
}

int main(){
    char *delimiters[] = {" ","&","<",">>",">", NULL};
    char data[]="cin>> num;";
    char *p;
    p = strpbrkEx(data, delimiters);//found ">>" but case of ">" distinction does not adhere
    printf("%s",p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`strpbrk` uses `char`s as delimiters, and `">>"` is not a char so you cannot just use it as a delimiter. Since you already have `'>'` as a delimiter, you could make it a special case when you see two in a row.

Comment: @ron: Wouldn't know without seeing how you parse the input